# How to Add repeated columns in jasper reports.(Using jaspersoft studio)

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a requirement like the following but can't solve it and that's why I am here. I hope someone can help.

I need a report which contains 3 columns in jasper report. The column values are so small that all these 3 columns occupy just the one third of the page width. So, I want to make a report which is like as follows:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3  | Col1   Col2   Col3  | Col1   Col2   Col3
------------------    ------------------    ------------------
val1   val1   val1  | val3   val3   val3  | val5   val5   val5

val2   val2   val2  | val4   val4   val4  | val6   val6   val6
```

That means `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3` will be repeated.

Can you give me any suggestions regarding these issues in the jasper report?

Answer (score 0):

set the `columnCount` and `printOrder` properties of the report as follows,

- `columnCount="3"` it divided page into 3 columns
- `printOrder="Horizontal"` by default it is vertically. hence, it should be a horizontal

report.jrxml

```
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.13.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.5.1  -->
<jasperReport ----- name="report" columnCount="3" printOrder="Horizontal" ---->
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    -----
</jasperReport>
```